# Sending requests between end to end devices in ionic

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

hi im trying to send a request to a user when a button is pressed.

for example, user 1 sends a request, the request is sent to user2, and user2 receives the request and has the capability of rejecting this request with a couple of days.

and user 1 is notified by about the decision of user 2

how can this be done in ionic 2/3?
another thing to point is that my application is using firestore as a db.
thanks

Comment: Is this a quick request, like seconds, while user 1 waits for response ? Or is this a request that could take minutes/days before user 2 accepts the request? Well in both cases you'll need to build some sort of API that handles those requests. If the request is quick, I suggest you to use websockets.

Comment: I achieved similar thing with `Angularfire2`, when user register admin get a request and user can only view his page after admin approves. Have a look at it  [Doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2)

Comment: @Hareesh Hey, what exactly did you use in angularFire2?

Comment: @JoeriShoeby uhm no the response can take a couple of days